# where ejabberd stores users data on server side

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am currently able to register Jabber User ID from http://localhost:5280/xmpp-http-bind/register/

but i want to know that where ejabberd  stores data at the server side , as i haven't enable any 
database access in ***ejabberd.cfg*** file but still ejabberd remembers everything about users data those are registered previously.

The reason i want to know that is because i want to store those (existing ) user data in mysql and at the same time i want to know where ejabberd stores the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ejabberd uses mnesia database by defaul
2. During installation you can set ejabberd to use mysql https://support.process-one.net/doc/display/MESSENGER/Using+ejabberd+with+MySQL+native+driver

If you you want authenticate your existing users in  mysql database you can use external-authentication scripts in your favorite language http://www.ejabberd.im/extauth